# AMSMath package not working for csvautolongtable package

Tags: tables, amsmath, longtable, landscape

I have the following table:

```
ID,Ln,La,N$_{I}$,Period$_{I}$,$\sigma_{I}$
4,05:18:11.71,-00:01:35.7,13,45,3.56,1e-4
....
```

I am trying to create the table with the following code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,10pt]{aastex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scientific-notation=true]{siunitx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\citestyle{aa}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\kgsins}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\newcommand{\kgsdel}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\sout{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\label{section:apptable}
{\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{landscape}
\small
\csvautolongtable[
  table head=\caption{some table}\\\hline
               \csvlinetotablerow\\\hline
              \endfirsthead\hline
              \csvlinetotablerow\\\hline
              \endhead\hline
              \endfoot]{table_v15demo.csv}
  \end{landscape}
  \end{flushleft}
   \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

The code compiles normally when I write `sigma$_{I}$`, but does not compile when I write `$\sigma_{I}$` and instead get the following error:

> Missing \endcsname inserted.  
>                     \sigma l.711                \endfoot]{table_v15demo.csv}
>
> The control sequence marked  should not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is unrelated to amsmath, as you would have noticed if you had made a minimal example such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable}


\begin{document}


\csvautolongtable[
  table head=\caption{some table}\\\hline
               \csvlinetotablerow\\\hline
              \endfirsthead\hline
              \csvlinetotablerow\\\hline
              \endhead\hline
              \endfoot]{table_v15demo.csv}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that you are making internal macro names for the headings from the content of the first row and that can not work if you have non-expandable commands there. One possibility would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable}

\def\xsigma{\ifmmode\sigma\else\string\sigma\fi}
\begin{document}


\csvautolongtable[
  table head=\caption{some table}\\\hline
               \csvlinetotablerow\\\hline
              \endfirsthead\hline
              \csvlinetotablerow\\\hline
              \endhead\hline
              \endfoot]{table_v15demo.csv}

\end{document}
```

which uses `\string` to make the `\sigma` safe when not being typeset.

the csv file would then be

```
ID,Ln,La,N$_{I}$,Period$_{I}$,$\xsigma_{I}$
4,05:18:11.71,-00:01:35.7,13,45,3.56,1e-4
```